# Say $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are two sequences such that $|X_n - Y_n| < 1/n$ and $\lim X_n =z$. Prove $\lim Y_n =z$.

Tags: real-analysis

a. Say $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are two sequences such that $|X_n-Y_n| < \frac{1}{n}$ and $\lim X_n$ = $z$. Prove $\lim Y_n$ = $z$.

b. Say $X_n$ takes values in closed interval $[a,b]$ and $\lim X_n$ = $z$. Prove $z$ takes values in closed interval $[a,b]$.

c. Does b. hold when the interval is open?

Comment: I give you a hint to start with: $$|y_n - z| = |y_n - x_n + x_n - z| \leq |y_n - x_n| + |x_n - z|$$

Comment: @Nameless that's almost an entire proof. Perhaps just a few little things need to be observed.

Comment: I set abs(xn-z) < ε, so abs(xn-yn)+abs(xn-z)< 1/n + ε. How can I show this is smaller than ε? Since I need to show abs(yn-z)<ε to prove limit of yn goes to z. @Nameless

Answer (score 3):

The hypothesis is the same as saying $|Y_n-X_n|<\frac{1}{n}$, or
$$
X_n-\frac{1}{n}<Y_n<X_n+\frac{1}{n}
$$
Can you say what
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(X_n-\frac{1}{n}\right)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(X_n+\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
are?

For (b), prove that $z=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n<a$ leads to a contradiction (take $\varepsilon=(a-z)/2$); similarly to exclude $z>b$.

For (c), what's $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$? Are the terms in $(0,2)$? That is, can you check at what happens when $X_n=1/n$, $a=0$ and $b=2$?

Comment: Could you expand on c?

Comment: @Sally $X_n=1/n$, $a=0$, $b=2$.

Answer (score 1):

a) Let $N$: $\forall n > N$ $\ \ \ |X_n - z|  < \frac{1}{n}$.

$|z - Y_n| < |z - X_n| + |X_n - Y_n| < \frac{2}{n}$ for $n > N$.

b) If not than $\exists$ $\epsilon $ : $z \in (z - \epsilon, z + \epsilon)$ because $\mathbb{R} / [a,b]$ is open.

But $\exists N$: $\forall n > N$ $\ \ \ |X_n - z| < \epsilon$ - contradiction.

c) If interval open then $X_n = b - \frac{1}{n}$ from interval but $\lim X_n$ = $b$ not.

Comment: Can you set abs(Xn-z) to be < 1/n? Shouldn't it be < ε?

Comment: We can for all $\epsilon > 0$ find $n$ : $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$  because $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ if $n \to \infty$.